# How to prevent bash script from putting all output into one line?

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I have the following bash script `top_script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
# "Usage: $0 JOBNAME LOGFILE"
JOBNAME=$1
LOGFILE=$2
JOB_OUTPUT=$($1 2>&1)
echo ${JOB_OUTPUT} >> "${LOGFILE}"
```

that is supposed to be invoked like this

```
top_script.sh script_to_run.sh log.txt
```

If `script_to_run.sh` has multiple `echo` statements, e.g.

```
echo Line 1 from $0
echo Line 2 from $0
```

then what I get in `log.txt` is

```
Line 1 from script_to_run.sh Line 2 from script_to_run.sh
```

i.e. all this output gets concatenated into a single line. I suspect that the reason is line #5 in the first code block above. How can I modify it to ensure separate `echo`s print into separate lines in `log.txt`?

Not that it really matters, but in case you are wondering, `top_script.sh` gets generated automatically form some a config file.

Comment: Quote your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "${JOB_OUTPUT}" >> "${LOGFILE}"
```